# What does a LinkedHashMap create in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, linkedhashmap

I am new to Kotlin and came across many instances in documentation where the `common`, `js`, `native` and `jvm` tags list different return values or class types. Could anyone please explain what exactly does that mean?

Here is an example:

[image]

My two question here are:

1. How are `class`, `typealias` and `open class` different?
2. Why do they seem to return different values for creating the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is telling you what you can expect the declaration of `LinkedHashMap` to look like, when writing code on different platforms - Kotlin/JS, Kotlin/JVM, Kotlin/Native. The "common" declaration is sort of the "intersection" of the other three - the "common" things among the three, which is useful if you are writing cross-platform code.

To explain each in detail (notice all 3 platforms is a "superset" of common):

Common:

```
class LinkedHashMap<K, V> : MutableMap<K, V>
```

`LinkedHashMap` is a class that has two generic parameters `K` and `V`, and it implements `MutableMap<K, V>`.

JVM:

```
typealias LinkedHashMap<K, V> = LinkedHashMap<K, V>
```

`LinkedHashMap<K, V>` is a *typealias* (i.e. another name) for Java's `java.util.LinkedHashMap<K, V>` class. The package name `java.util` is not shown in the documentation itself, which might be confusing, but you can click on the link to find out :)

Notice that `java.util.LinkedHashMap<K, V>` implements `java.util.Map<K, V>`, which when ported to Kotlin, means that it implements `MutableMap<K, V>`. (I say this because this is one of the things in the common declaration)

JS:

```
open class LinkedHashMap<K, V> : 
    HashMap<K, V>, 
    MutableMap<K, V>
```

`LinkedHashMap` is a class that has two generic parameters `K` and `V`, and it implements `MutableMap<K, V>`. It also inherits from `HashMap<K, V>`, and it is `open`, which means that you can inherit from it.

Native:

```
typealias LinkedHashMap<K, V> = HashMap<K, V>
```

`LinkedHashMap<K, V>` is just another name for `HashMap<K, V>` (this time it's Kotlin's `kotlin.collections.HashMap`, not Java's. Click the link to find out.) Also note that `HashMap<K, V>` implements `MutableMap<K, V>` too.

> Why do they seem to return different values for creating the same thing?

These are not functions, and they don't return anything. These are *declarations* for the class `LinkedHashMap`, and some platforms may declare them differently, because they're different platforms! For example, why would Kotlin/JVM make an entirely new `LinkedHashMap`, when there is already one in the JDK? So they just say that `kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap` is just another name for `java.util.HashMap`. Another example is Kotlin/Native: it appears that the `HashMap` that they implemented is already linked, so again, we don't need a totally new class.

As long as what they implement on these different platforms satisfy the requirements of the "common" declaration (namely two generic type parameters `K` and `V`, and implements `MutableMap<K, V>`), they're fine.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, most of the information in the docs is not relevant, when on the JVM. If you type `LinkedHashMap<String, String>()`, you actually (because of the JVM only type alias) create a java.util.LinkedHashMap, thus the way the LinkedHashMap of kotlin is “implemented” on the JVM is using the java built-in. If you call linkedMapOf, however, you get back an instance of the kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap<K, V> class, but if you look at the reflected type (::class) it is actually still a java.util.LinkedHashMap! So, we can conclude the following out of this:

1. On the JVM, collection types of the java stdlib are used (because the compiler changes constructor invocations to kotlin collections, to invocations of java ones)
2. There is a common class or interface that exists so you don’t have to write different code on different platforms, a different type may be used on runtime, however.
3. When using JS, LinkedHashMap can be overridden (because it is `open`), and it is the “implementer” of the expected LinkedHashMap type.
4. When using native targets, because the order is preserved when using a normal HashMap, LinkedHashMap points to there because there is no reason for using a linked hashmap instead of a normal one

Edit: just realized I didn’t really answer your question:

1. a class is just your regular oop class, but it can’t be overridden because it is open, typealias means that when you reference a certain type it actually “points” to a different type (you can see it as a type rename, or reexport), and an open class is a class that can be extended/overridden
2. Because of platform-specific implementations. This structure or expect + actual allows you to write common code for all platforms without having to worry about an individual platform.

I hope this answers your questions, let me know if you have any more.