# How does Kotlin retrieve map values internally with its get function

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin you create a map like this:

`val items = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)`

and retrieve a value like this:

`val item = items["a"]`

The bracket will call the `get` function. Looking at Kotlin's the source code for Maps, all that I see for the `get` function is this:

```
public operator fun get(key: K): V?
```

I couldn't find any implementation of `get`, so it's not clear how Kotlin internally finds a map item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you create the Kotlin map, different implementation may be created. But in the concrete case of `mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2)` a `kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap` will be created. `LinkedHashMaps` implementation depends on the target platform. More information can be found here: [What does a LinkedHashMap create in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71891601/what-does-a-linkedhashmap-create-in-kotlin). If the target platform is JVM then the underlying implementation if `java.util.HashMap` and it's get function.

Comment: Going through the Kotlin source code, I notice that it eventually calls the platform specific function, which is typically the Java function. So I would have to look at the Java implementation to see how it's done.

Comment: @Johann Looking through the Kotlin source code can be very interesting — but you shouldn't rely on what you see there: later versions can change the implementation (e.g. to improve performance or portability, or support new features). Anything spelled out in the documentation is pretty much guaranteed, but implementation details aren't. — However, in this case `kotlin.collections.Map` is documented as a mapped type (see eSemy's answer), so you can rely on it calling some implementation of `java.util.Map.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Mapped types

For most Java types, Kotlin will just use the definition as provided. But for some types, Kotlin decides to treat them specially, and completely replace the Java definition with its own version. These types are known as *mapped types*.

You can see [the list of mapped types in the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types), and `Map` is one of them.

[image: table of mapped types, showing Java Map<K, V> is mapped to Kotlin Map<K, V>]

This means that [`kotlin.collections.Map.get()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/2cd16f055acb685e878c04127fe6071d287e231f/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Collections.kt#LL317-L320) does not have a visible implementation - but it will be provided (eventually) by the actual Java `Map` implementation.

#### Why does Kotlin map types?

Why is this necessary? One reason is that it improves null-safety.

The Java implementation of `Map.get()` returns a non-nullable value.

```java
// Java Map getter - V is not marked as nullable
public V get(Object key) { ... }
```

Because `V` is a [platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types), Kotlin would assume it is *not* null (for convenience - otherwise every usage of Java code would be saturated with null checks).

To avoid confusion, Kotlin's `Map.get()` specifically marks the return value as nullable.

```kotlin
// Kotlin Map getter - V is explicitly marked as nullable
public operator fun get(key: K): V?
```

Now in Kotlin we can safely retrieve values from `Map`s, even if they're missing. Phew! Crisis averted.

#### See also

[What are nullable rules when calling Java from Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72480608/4161471)

Answer (score -1):

The operator `[]` is implemented as `get` on the various `Map` implementations, see for example default map [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/9a69c1dd35eea0006909eb16eb76d852601f51d3/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/MapWithDefault.kt#L67) and empty map [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/9a69c1dd35eea0006909eb16eb76d852601f51d3/compiler/testData/codegen/box/specialBuiltins/emptyMap.kt#L9).